# Python pyodbc cursor.execute(query) not working on a .exe compilation

Tags: python, sql, windows, pyodbc

I'm trying to create an alert with Python that connects to a SQL database, executes a SELECT, and based on the results, sends an alert via SMTP. I got it all down, it works when executing the Python script from Visual Studio. But if I compile it to .exe with pyinstaller (which I need to execute from the Windows Task Scheduler on a server that does not have Python installed) and try to run it, it stops on the line that executes the query. Here is the code:

```py
for BM in servers: 
        try:
            server = BM[0]
            db = BM[1]

            conn = pyodbc.connect('driver={%s};server=%s;database=%s;uid=%s;pwd=%s' % ( driver, server, db, user, password ) )
            log.write("Conectado" + '\n')

            cursor = conn.cursor()
            log.write("Cursor creado" + '\n')

            try:
                cursor.execute(query)
                log.write("Query ejecutada" + '\n')

            except pyodbc.Error as ex:
                log.write(ex + '\n')

        except pyodbc.Error as ex:
            log.write(ex + '\n')
```

The line that stops the script is cursor.execute(query). And "query" is a simple SELECT * FROM table, no conditions.

How can I make this work?

Comment: And nothing appears in the logs to indicate what the problem might be?

Comment: Nothing, it just stops. It writes the first two log.write but never gets to the tird.

Comment: Does the process terminate or does it hang?

Comment: Terminates. The window closes.